# jQuery: On click, prevent mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have two seperate animations that are occurring, one fires on `mouseenter` the other on `click`. The problem is that when they are both activated it creates a jumpy animation.

You can see what I mean here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDAYt/)

Is it possible to prevent the `mouseenter` event from occurring if the `click` event is activated?

**Javascript**

```
$('header h1').mouseenter(function() {
  $('header:not(.open)').delay(500).animate({
    'padding-bottom': '40px'
  }, 150, function() {
    //function complete
  });
});

$('header h1').mouseleave(function() {
  $('header:not(.open)').animate({
    'padding-bottom': '20px'
  }, 150, function() {
    //function complete
  });
});

$('header h1').click(function() {

  if ($('header').hasClass('open')) {
    $('header p').fadeOut(100);
    $('header').removeClass('open').animate({
      'padding-bottom': '20px'
    }, 300, function() {
      //animation complete
    });
  }

  else {
    $('header').addClass('open').animate({
      'padding-bottom': '150px'
    }, 300, function() {
      $('header p').fadeIn();
    });
  }

});​
```

Comment: Why do you need to delay for half a second?

Comment: @mayhewr I added the delay to emphasize the problem. But it still exists regardless.

Comment: Looks like unbind might work? http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Did the answer you chose fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems easier to just do this :

```
$('header').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (!$(this).is('.open')) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).delay(500).animate({'padding-bottom': '40px' }, 150, function() {
                //function complete
            });
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
        if (!$(this).is('.open')) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({'padding-bottom': '20px'}, 150, function() {
            //function complete
            });
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        if ($(this).is('.open')) {
            $(this).find('p').fadeOut(100).end().removeClass('open').stop(true, true).animate({'padding-bottom': '20px'}, 300, function() {
                //animation complete
            });
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('open').stop(true, true).animate({'padding-bottom': '150px'}, 300, function() {
                $('p', this).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Especially because those events are based on each other: To click on an element, you need to enter it with the mouse: You can't deactivate the `enter` event which already happened when you click. And you obviously shouldn't deactivate future `click` events when entering.

The solution to your problem with the jumping animations should be the [`stop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which ends running animations on the selected elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Any help implementing the `stop()` method would be appreciated

Comment: Just insert .stop() before .animate(...)

Answer (score 0):

How about checking for the `open` class after the delay.

Changing from

```
$('header h1').mouseenter(function() {
  $('header:not(.open)').delay(500).animate({
    'padding-bottom': '40px'
  }, 150, function() {
    //function complete
  });
});
```

to

```
$('header h1').mouseenter(function() {
  $.delay(500);
  $('header:not(.open)').animate({
    'padding-bottom': '40px'
  }, 150, function() {
    //function complete
  });
});
```

Obviously you can fine-tune the delay to your liking, but the idea would be something like:

If they don't click before `x` milliseconds, increase padding.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Add this to the beginning of your `click` event:

```
$('header').stop(true)
```

The first parameter for true is `clearQueue`, which will clear your animation queue.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NznC8/).